# App Delegate to Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an NSURL property in my app delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *openedURL;
```

...and then:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
         openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
      annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
self.openedURL = url;
// attempt to extract a token from the url
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];       
}
```

I want to move this code to a normal UIViewController. How can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the appdelegade can have the `openURL:` handler, but you can just call a method in any of your controllers, or any NSObject, and perform the code you wish there.

Comment: Just call the UIViewController with the function. You can ask the current root view controller to handle it by just going [self.window.rootViewController performSelector:@selector(whatever) withObject:url];